# Remove floating JToolbar

Tags: java, swing, floating, jtoolbar

I have a `JButton` in my application to add/remove a `JToolBar`. When the toolbar is docked, I can remove it using:

```
toolBar.getParent().remove(toolbar); // toolBar is an instance of JToolBar
```

If I do this while the toolbar is floating, nothing happens, the floating toolbar remains there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the BasicToolBarUI object obtained from the JToolBar, we can know if it floating. If the JToolbar is floating, we can dispose its window.

```
public boolean isFloating(JToolBar toolbar) {
  ToolBarUI ui = toolbar.getUI();
  return ui instanceof BasicToolBarUI && ( (BasicToolBarUI) ui).isFloating();
}

public void removeFromParent(JToolBar toolbar) {
  if (isFloating(toolbar)) {
    // Dock the JToolBar before removing
    BasicToolBarUI basicToolbarUI = (BasicToolBarUI) toolbar.getUI();
    basicToolbarUI.setFloating(false, null);
  }
  // Not floating, docked, remove from parent component
  toolbar.getParent().remove(toolbar);
}
```